# MS Access dates switching up on me

Tags: sql-server, date, ms-access, vba

I have a query that populates a continuous subform with records from SQL Server. When I just have my code as the one below, it populates everything normally.

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE StartDate <= 42720 and EndDate >= 42720"
```

But when I add the or condition at the end (see below), my dates are suddenly offset by 2! (2 days BEFORE the query above).

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE StartDate <= 42720 and EndDate >= 42720 or ID = 16801;"
```

I know MS Access has a weird thing where it differs from SQL Server by 2 because it counts 1900 as a leap year and starts at 1 instead of 0. But why is this happening at this point? This makes me sad.

edit: None of the answers so far told me WHY adding an `ID =` condition suddenly changes the date interpretation from SQL to Access, but one answer resolves the issue so I've marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your criteria needs a basic correction:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE (StartDate <= 42720 and EndDate >= 42720) or ID = 16801;"
```

Second, you should always specify dates as date values, not numbers, not strings, no exceptions. Thus:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE (StartDate <= #2016/12/16# and EndDate >= #2016/12/16#) or ID = 16801;"
```

or:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE (StartDate <= DateSerial(2016,12,16) and EndDate >= DateSerial(2016,12,16) or ID = 16801;"
```

Comment: I believe brackets should not affect results because `and` executed always before `or`, but anyway, agree that explicit execution sequence would be better

Comment: You are right. _Between-And_ is evaluated first, then the two sides of _Or_.

Comment: So I need to have my SQL view convert the date to a date value string which I use in my VBA?

Comment: No, but date values concatenated into an SQL string (first example) must be formatted as string expressions. Date values from functions (second example) are used _as is_.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the date number IS from SQL. I used string concatenation, but I've simplified it for this question. I think I'll go with having StartYear, StartMonth, etc. and go with your second formatting scheme. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT viewTask.* FROM viewTask WHERE (StartDate <= 42720 and EndDate >= 42720) or ID = 16801;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in first case SQL evaluated on SQL server side - directly passed to SQL server, in this case number converted to date on SQL side, which interprets 0 as 1/1/1900. Second Select already evaluated on Access side first, it converts number to date by Access rules, where 0 is 1/31/1899, and then it passed to SQL server already with dates in arguments. You can catch SQL passed to SQL server in both cases and verify my version.

So, be very careful with using numbers instead of explicit dates when you work with server, which has different conversion rules with Access. You cannot be sure, that SQL passed to the server without additional evaluation on Access side if you don't use SQL Pass-through queries.